# Why does Bash eat the first letter from every second line of input when redirecting ffmpeg stderr to stdout?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, stdin

When I run the following code, that is supposed to print out the filename and redirect ffmpeg's stderr information to stdout:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r filename; do
  echo $filename
  cmd_out=$(ffmpeg -i "$filename" -f null - 2>&1)
done < inputs.txt
```

With the following `inputs.txt`:

```
intro.mp3
silence.mp3
outro.mp3
intro2.mp3
```

I get

```
intro.mp3
ilence.mp3
outro.mp3
ntro2.mp3
```

Notice the first letter of the filename is missing in both the 2nd and 4th lines.

This happens only if the `inputs.txt` entries are existing audio files, and ffmpeg is used.

Comment: if you comment out (or remove) the `cmd_out=$(...)` line (ie, leaving just the `echo`), do you get the same output?  if so, might be of interest to see if `inputs.txt` contains any non-printing characters; can you update the question with the output from `od -c inputs.txt` or `xxd inputs.txt`

Comment: I suspect `ffmpeg` is reading a character for some reason. Try adding `</dev/null` to the end of the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: See ["Strange errors when using ffmpeg in a loop"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36310/strange-errors-when-using-ffmpeg-in-a-loop) and [BashFAQ #89: "I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)